# division of two proper kernels

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Let [image] be proper kernels. Does it imply that

[image]

is a proper kernel? prove or give a counter example. It seems wrong but I didn't find how to prove it. Any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: that is more a question for dsp or math

Comment: @dynamic but it stands in the heart of svm method. Do you mean that I need to ask it in math exchange?

Comment: This is probably off-topic for stackoverflow. I think it should be migrated to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @cel how can I do that?

Comment: @Shlomi, we can't do that. I raised a flag to mark this question as a candidate for migration. If the community agrees, it will be moved eventually.

Comment: @cel agreed about migration to stats: have so indicated/voted

Answer (score 0):

K2(x,z) can be 0.

Then this value is not well-defined.

Therefore, this is not a proper kernel.

Comment: assume it is always not equal to 0.